# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level [Finished in 0.1s]

Tags: python

When I compile the Python code below, I get
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    import sys
    f_contents= f.read(100)
    print(f_contents,end='')
    f_contents= f.read(100)
    print(f_contents,end='')
```

Can any body explain why that happens?

Comment: The error is very clear IndentationError, Refer this https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/

Comment: You've got mixed tabs and spaces. That's the problem. Don't mix them.

Answer (score 0):

Working for me!

Can you show the exact line where the error occurred and the input file

Possible reason:
If this part of some file, then you might be using mix of tabs and spaces

[image]

Code I used:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    import sys 
    f_contents= f.read(100)
    print(f_contents,end='')
    f_contents= f.read(100)
    print(f_contents,end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation of your code matters in Python, the code won't run if the indentation is not correct. The code you posted, should be indented as follows. The `with` statement needs an indent (like an `if` statement or `for` loop would).

```py
import sys

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    f_contents = f.read(100)
    print(f_contents,end='')
    f_contents= f.read(100)
    print(f_contents,end='')
```

Note: `import sys` isn't needed for that bit of code to run, but usually you should have import statements at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     with open('test.txt','r') as f:
         import sys
         f_contents= f.read(100)
         print(f_contents,end='')
         f_contents= f.read(100)
         print(f_contents,end='')
```

with require proper indentation